# difference between raising and rising

Tags: american-english, vocabulary

If I were to say "my grades weren't raising/rising"; which one is correct?
are they used interchangeably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raised: usually increased by action of third party.
Rised: increased by  itself.

Comment: #Lukas - You are correct, except that the past tense of 'rise' is 'rose'. 'Raise' is a transitive verb; you raise your hand.